# Calculating how many arrangements of the balls can be made

Tags: probability

> There are 5 different sizes of white ball and five different sizes of
>   green balls. When these 10 balls are laid out in a line so that
>   adjacent balls can have different colors, how many arrangements of the
>   balls can be made?

Which method can i use to solve this?

I kind of don't really understand the question? If "**adjacent balls can have different colors**" so it means the order haas to be like this : white - green - white - green - white - green ..... and so on

So how come there are so many possible arrangements to satisfy the question?

Comment: Do you mean by "adjacent balls can have different colours" that adjacent balls **must** have different colours, or do you mean that it is ok if they have different colours?

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA I don't really understand the question too.

Comment: Question is very unclear.  What is considered a different arrangement?  Also it is not clear what color combinations are allowed because of your wording.  The way you have the question worded, there are infinitely many arrangements.

Comment: @David the problem is solved, thanks, different arrangments means size difference, and my wording does not have any problems, I copied the question directly from the source, an exam.

Comment: @f855a864: I disagree.  Do you know what a line is?  If so, then you would not have accepted any answer other than infinitely many as correct.  Look at how many people (including yourself!) stated the question is not clear.

Comment: @David I was unclear at the begining, when I did not notice the size differences. And that's kinda rude of you to say something like "do you know what a line is?" , Yes I know

Comment: FYI: Zubin's answer below is correct, when i posted this, I already had the answer, but I didn't know how to solve it, so I came here for a better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two color choices: one that is determined by white first, and one by green first. For each of these choices, there are $5!$ arrangements of the balls of each color. This gives us $$2 \cdot \left(5!\right)^2 = 2 \cdot 120 \cdot 120 = \boxed{28800}$$

Comment: I don't really understand the question, can you elaborate more ? I edited my answer, please take a look

Comment: you can have white/green/white/green etc. or green/white/green/white etc., and for *each* of those there are $(5!)^2$ possibilities, because the balls are all different sizes, so you can tell them apart

Answer (score 1):

As it's written, the problem doesn't say that adjacent balls *must* have different colors, just that they *can*. Hence, since each ball is distinguishable from each other ball, there are exactly 10! arrangements

Answer (score 1):

Lines have infinite length so the balls can be placed on a line in infinitely many ways. Just change the spacing and that is a "new" arrangement.